# Physics particle collisions

Tags: java, object-oriented, modules, physics

I have a [large file](http://pastebin.com/iyGmTHF9) that I want to refactor.  My idea is to make helper classes with helper methods so that I can modularize methods.

Is that a good idea? For instance before refactoring:

```
public void collision(PhysicsCollisionEvent event) {
    if (event.getObjectA() instanceof BombControl) {
        final Spatial node = event.getNodeA();
        effect.killAllParticles();
        effect.setLocalTranslation(node.getLocalTranslation());
        BombControl bc = (BombControl) event.getObjectA();
        effect.emitAllParticles();
    } else if (event.getObjectB() instanceof BombControl) {
        final Spatial node = event.getNodeB();
        effect.killAllParticles();
        effect.setLocalTranslation(node.getLocalTranslation());
        effect.emitAllParticles();
    }
}
```

After refactoring:

```
public void collision(PhysicsCollisionEvent event) {
    CollisionHelper.collisionHelp(event, effect);
}
```

Is that a good idea or must I use a more elaborate recfactoring? I think it would work but I don't know of specific refactoring patterns.

Comment: In response to "I don't know of specific refactoring patterns," http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring provides a handy guide to many different types of refactoring.

Comment: Is that file your entire app, or do you already have other classes?

Comment: I'm not sure which Java version you are constrained to use, but since Java 7 you can `switch` on `String` instead of all the `else if` in `onAction`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of simple things I notice right off the bat.

1. If you have a method which only calls another method, why bother having the first method at all?  I'm personally against these one-line wrapper methods and see them as unnecessary noise.
2. Your methods should be verb phrases, in general (e.g., `CollisionHelper.helpCollision` or even `performCollision`, in this case, since it's doing all of your processing).
3. <s>I believe there's a standard for replacing `instanceof` usage with an actual method from the `Class` API, as follows: `BombControl.class.isInstance(event.getObjectA())`.  You can see more on [this Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692214/when-to-use-class-isinstance-when-to-use-instanceof-operator).</s>  (Apparently you're using it correctly here, however.)

From the comments: you obviously should move the entire huge method body to the helper method, otherwise you have the same problem.  Just [extract 'til you drop](https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/one-thing-extract-till-you-drop).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I suppose you didn't say any obvious pitfall my my "idea" where some other methods in the class are very large and can be modularized into helper methods that are in helper classes so that one method that is 800 rows now can call 8 methods in 8 helper classes so the original files gets more concise.

Comment: `isInstance()` is for when you have am instance of `Class` and don't know the exact class type. In this case, you know the exact class you are checking the type against, so `instanceof` is correct. It is also more legible than accessing the `class` variable.

Comment: @909Niklas: Are these helper classes going to be used by many different classes? If you just want to break a large method into smaller methods, there is no reason to move them into a different class. Just mark the sub-methods as private.

Comment: My "monolith" is abt 1100 rows and I prefer shorter files. So I want to end up with 5-10 smaller files / classes. And I would like to use them in another project too (since I use the same framework in 2 projects). I completed the first helper class and it has a static helper method but I think it also could have been an instance method.

Comment: @909Niklas Sure.  If you pull out the entire method body into a helper method, then you have the same problem.  But if you keep [extracting until you drop](https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/one-thing-extract-till-you-drop), you should be good. :)

Comment: @unholysampler Thanks for that clarification.

Answer (score 3):

I also hate large files.  My rule of thumb is a maximum of 300 lines per class.

You mentioned that you wanted to put methods in helper classes.  Also you said you were not sure about refactoring patterns.

Use the simplest refactoring: **OO**!

You should not just break things into helper methods and helper classes, but into real classes.  You have a full page of member variables declaration at the top of `UFOSpaceWorld`; those variables should be divided to appropriate classes.  It is always difficult to correctly break a program in classes.   You might have to try many different ways of breaking things down in classes before you find something that is satisfying. Make sure you use git or a version control system so that you can always go back.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use xp-dev for svn repo, chatted with the author of the library and we now have [decent physics code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0b6Q-rqRaI).